# Unable to dequeue messages from Rabbitmq using amqp package in node

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I enqueue my messages to Rabiitmq using the following node js code:

```
//enqueue.js
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Msg 1'));
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Msg 2'));
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Msg 3'));
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Msg 4'));
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Msg 5'));
  });
  setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
});
```

The enqueue process happens as intended.

Now I wish to dequeue just 1 message and for that I use this code:

```
//dequeue.js
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';
    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: true});
    ch.prefetch(1);
    ch.consume(q, function(msg) {
      console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    }, {noAck: false});
  });
});
```

As expected the output is:

```
 [x] Received Msg 1
```

But **Msg 1 is still in the queue** and it is not dequeued. So I tried adding `ch.ack(msg)` after the `console.log()` statement in `dequeue.js` but instead of just 1 message getting dequeued all the messages are getting dequeued!

Please help me to dequeue just 1 message.

Answer (score 0):

Set noack to true.

> noAck (boolean): if true, the message will be assumed by the server to
>   be acknowledged (i.e., dequeued) as soon as it's been sent over the
>   wire. Default is false, that is, you will be expected to acknowledge
>   the message.

http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_get

Or remove the noack and make sure you check that msg !== null (if you call ch.ack() on a null object, it's just going to throw a channel exception).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I am facing the same issue all the time, I want to **dequeue just 1** message but all the five messages that I have enqueued get dequeued!